# Gunicorn Worker timeout in Django request hosted on cloud foundry

Tags: django, gunicorn, cloud-foundry

We have an Angular + Django application hosted on cloud foundry. I have written some APIs, out of them there is one API which inconsistently fails with error:

WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:120)

This request transfers a lot of data (~35MB) and sometime the response comes and sometime the request fails with error:

net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)

I have searched for similar problem. I could see solutions saying about increasing the timeout in gunicorn configuration file. But I don't have any such file. We use a procfile with content as:

web: gunicorn ApplicationName.wsgi:application

So, how can I increase the timeout.

And also, Would increasing the timeout have any affect on application.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify configuration options to gunicorn in a number of ways. From the docs:

1. Environment Variables
2. Framework Settings
3. Configuration File
4. GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS
5. Command Line

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html

My suggestion would be 3 or 5. If you have a configuration file already, just add it there. If you don't, add it as a command line argument, which you'd just set in your as an argument to the command in your `Procfile`.

Ex:

```
web: gunicorn --timeout 45 package:app
```

I would suggest you avoid using 4, `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS`, because the buildpack uses this to set some default settings which are necessary when you run on Cloud Foundry. If you set this, it will override the buildpack and its default value.

At the time of writing, the buildpack is setting the following default:

```
export GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS=${GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS:-'--access-logfile -'}
```

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/blob/master/src/python/supply/supply.go#L702

If you really wanted to use this option, you could. You would just need to include the default values or you'd lose logging from Gunicorn. The main risk here would be if the buildpack changes its defaults in the future. Then you would be out-of-sync.

---

As a side note, you may want to look at the async worker options as well. If you have code that is primarily waiting, like for I/O, this can be a better, more scalable option (as opposed to increasing the timeout).

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#choosing-a-worker-type

You can do that by installing the packages for your async worker of choice.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/install.html#async-workers

Then add the `--worker-class <worker>` flag to the arguments in your Procfile start command (or using any other Gunicorn support config method). Note - you don't need to include `--timeout` when using this option.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class

Ex:

```
pip install gunicorn[eventlet]
gunicorn --worker-class eventlet package:app
```

Comment: Adding to Procfile worked. Thank you for the suggestions.